# Locally modifying animator controllers of standard 3rd person

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

When I drag a standard 3rd person character controller's `animator controller` and drop it on the `Animator` field of a character and then modify it, is it only the animator controller of that character I am changing locally, or is it the original standard one?

I thought it would be the former and so I could experiment with it, learning how to add animation states, code, etc... but the next time I dragged a standard one and dropped it on a character, it wouldn't work, as if I had broken it.

So, I had to import the entire `Standard Assets` again, but I wondered how I could play with animation and coding and stuff **locally**, without affecting the original standard ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create how many animator controllers assets you want, this is an asset that you can create by Assets\Create\AnimatorController menu if I remember well (I can't open unity right now).

Name It as you want and it will be available from your assets folder, just drag each one of them to "Controller" field of your "Animator Component" on your character and play around.

To see state machines of each animator controller asset on animator view you need to select the asset on projects folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand what you are saying, but if I just create an `animator controller` and re-name it, etc... it will be an empty one. Right? Eventually, I will have to drop on it the standard `3rd person animator controller` (for example) to take advantage of its default states and transitions. Correct?

Comment: Almost correct. You can make copies of your assets to "fork/branche" your current state machine and try something new from where you are on your current one. Also you can make another copies of your character or asset that uses the animation controller asset on its component animator to avoid change/drop it every time (Character01 uses AnimControl01, Character02 uses AnimControl02...). Summarizing, they are just simples assets that you can copy and maintain lots of individual instances you just need to understand their relationship well enough to avoid unwanted overwrites ;)

Comment: Great help. Thank you!